# My Twitter php script stopped working!

Tags: php, api, class, twitter

I'm using this PHP class for a Twitter script:

twitter.slawcup.com/twitter.class.phps

The script is:

```
$t= new twitter();
$t->username='someuser';
$t->password='somepass';
$res = $t->update($tweet);
if($res===false){
   echo "ERROR<hr/>";
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($t->responseInfo);
   echo "</pre>";
}else{
   echo "SUCCESS<hr/>Status Posted";
}
```

Where the variable $tweet is a string generated before.

It worked ok un until june 8th, and then it just died.

Now, when I run the code, it gives me:

```
ERROR
Array
(
    [url] => http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
    [content_type] => application/xml; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 1096
    [request_size] => 120
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.11795
    [namelookup_time] => 3.3E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.014397
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.014405
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 148
    [speed_download] => 1254
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 148
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.117829
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

What could be wrong? It's specially weird because it was working ok, and then it stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was my hosting provider's fault. PHP was not properly set up.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning Error Code 400 if you check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes the error code says

```
Bad Request
The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled.
```

This would relate to something wrong with the class... but it is hard to see without checking code.

**##Make sure you have the lastest version of the class.##**

Comment: This, with the addition that - if your code is otherwise unchanged, it's also likely that twitter is just having difficulties at the moment. I'd verify that the right syntax is being sent to Twitter via their API docs.

Answer (score 1):

What authentication schema are you using?
Twitter will deprecate support for auth-basic, even if it still works, i'd consider migrating to Oauth soon.